# Is there a way to run IHaskell using a particular sandbox directory?

Tags: haskell, cabal, ihaskell

Exactly that - can I run IHaskell and have it load packages from a particular sandbox directory?

Comment: Could you just install IHaskell and the packages into the same sandbox?

Comment: Would `cabal exec` as [suggested in this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28141946/1088108) work for IHaskell?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using stack to manage your iHaskell instance, you can edit the `stack.yaml` file to include dependencies by listing them under the packages section. For example, say you want to include foo and bar that are located in folder `foobar` your `stack.yaml` would have:

```
packages:
  - foobar/foo
  - foobar/bar
```