# Why cabal sandbox init does not change PATH like virtualenv does?

Tags: haskell, sandbox, cabal, package-managers

Haskell newbie and Python guy here.

I think I may be missing something here but if you look at [Yesod's quickstart](http://www.yesodweb.com/page/quickstart), the autor install some packages **before** `cabal sandbox init`. I have seen the same pattern elsewhere. Questions:

1. Am I missing something? Is this the real way to use cabal sandbox?
2. Why can't (or shouldn't) I install yesod-bin inside a sandbox?
3. What if I use different versions of yesod-bin throughout some projects?
4. If there is some libraries that install binaries inside .cabal-sandbox/bin, why `cabal sandbox init` don't change PATH in order to match the sandboxed version?

Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1. Yes, this how to use a sandbox.

   `cabal sandbox init` will create some files / directories for you that will keep track of the packages you have installed.

   `cabal install some_package` will install that package into the sandbox.
2. You are more than welcome to install `yesod-bin` into a sandbox.
3. Read point 2
4. `cabal sandbox init` doesn't change your path, because it doesn't really need to. Just add `PATH=.cabal-sandbox/bin:$PATH` in your `.bash_profile`.

   Unlike virtual-env, you never need to 'enable' or 'disable' a sandbox. You just `cd` into a directory, and it is automatically enabled.

   The only real downside I have found to cabal sandboxes, is that you need to be in the root directory in order to act upon a sandbox. Meaning, if you are in a sub-directory, running `cabal install some_package` will not install it into the sandbox that is up a level, instead it will install it into either the global or user database, depending on how you have `cabal` configured.

Comment: Better than I thought. Thank you!

Comment: If you are not in the root directory of the cabal sandbox, you can still work in that sandbox by pointing cabal to the correct config file: `cabal --config=<path>\cabal.sandbox.config <command>`.

Answer (score 6):

`cabal exec` lets you execute a program in the context of a sandbox. It changes the path to include the `bin` folder of the sandbox. You can see it by executing `cabal exec printenv` inside the sandbox.

Also, the latest versions of `cabal` let you create sandboxes in folders without `.cabal` files. Once you run `cabal sandbox init`, you can just `cabal install` the dependencies you need.

So, to use different versions of `yesod-bin`, install them in different sandboxes, and then invoke `cabal exec yesod-bin` on each one.

(Extra tip: `cabal exec gchi` is a useful command that makes `ghci` aware of the contents of the sandbox.)